# Husky pre commit hook and squashing commits

Tags: bash, git, husky

I am using `"husky": "^7.0.4"`.

My team squashes their commits before opening a PR.

I have a `pre-commit` file to automate this workflow. Every other time I run the commit function, the pre-commit flow works perfectly. So the 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. works. The 2nd, 4th, 6th, etc time prints this error

```sh
fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': is at 766hdjoXXX but expected 766e11XXX
```

I thought it might be because I wasn't changing the file, however when I tried changing something, that didn't work either(it succeeds and fails every other time regardless). Any idea what's wrong?

Here is the `pre-commit` file:

```sh
read -n1 -p "Do you want to squash commits? [n/Y]" SHOULD_SQUASH < /dev/tty

case $SHOULD_SQUASH in  
  n|N) 
    echo
    echo Skipping squash, now linting files...
    ;;
  y|Y) 
    [ -z "$SQUASH_BRANCH" ] && SQUASH_BRANCH=develop
    branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)
    echo
    echo Squashing all commits from $branch
    git reset $(git merge-base $SQUASH_BRANCH $branch)
    echo ------SUCCESS!------
    echo Commits successfully squashed.
    git add .
    echo Added all files successfully.
    ;;
  *) 
    echo
    echo Skipping squash, now linting files...
    ;;
esac

npx pretty-quick --staged
npm run lint
```

The squash function is from a custom function, that works with no problem, we created that lives in `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-commit files in general *should not* use `git reset` and `git add`.  It is possible to make this work *sometimes*, but you get odd effects, including the one you're seeing (and sometimes worse ones).  A pre-commit script should limit itself to *testing whether the commit is OK*, and if so, exiting zero; if not, the script should exit nonzero, without attempting to make any changes.<sup>1</sup>

Instead of calling your script `.git/pre-commit` and invoking it with `git commit`, call it `makecommit` and invoke it as `makecommit`.  Or, call it `git-c` and invoke it as `git c`.  Have the script do its thing—including run `npm lint`—and if all looks good, have it run `git commit`.  You won't need a pre-commit hook at all, but if you like, you can have one that reads as follows:

```
[ "$RUN_FROM_OUR_SCRIPT" = yes ] && exit 0
echo "don't run git commit directly, run our script instead"
exit 1
```

Then instead of just `git commit`, have your script do:

```
RUN_FROM_OUR_SCRIPT=yes git commit
```

which will set the variable that the pre-commit hook tests to make sure `git commit` was run from your script.

Note that you will no longer need to redirect the `read` from `/dev/tty`.  (You probably should also consider using `git reset --soft`, and/or verifying the that index content matches the working tree content.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you like to live dangerously, and *really want* to have a script that can update files, make sure that `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` is unset or set to `.git/index`, to make sure you have not been invoked as `git commit --only`.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I added in the `post-commit` hook that seems to work perfectly, do you foresee any issue with that?

Comment: It's not dangerous, exactly, but users who are familiar with Git won't expect a post-commit hook to run `git add`, so it's probably still not a good idea.

Comment: wonderful, I added in a bash script to run this. appreciate your help!